# Order is cancel automatically in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a problem in my webite. Our order is automaticly canceled . may be there is time setting somewhere, but i am not able to find that. i check the cron module but i think that is not responsible for this issue.

[image]

```
   $now = time();
        $timeAhead = $now + $scheduleAheadFor;
        $schedule->setJobCode($jobCode)
            ->setCronExpr($cronExpr)
            ->setStatus(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_PENDING);

        for ($time = $now; $time < $timeAhead; $time += 60) {
            $ts = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', $time);
            if (!empty($exists[$jobCode.'/'.$ts])) {
                // already scheduled
                continue;
            }
            if (!$schedule->trySchedule($time)) {
                // time does not match cron expression
                continue;
            }
            $schedule->unsScheduleId()->save();
        }
```

can you please tell me where i change the time or completely disable this automatically cancel function.